# Why am I getting 404 on swagger ui on Spring Boot 3.1.5?

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger-ui

I am trying to integrate the Springdoc open-api definition into my project. Currently for some strange reason /v3/api-docs is working properly, it is getting the JSON version of API but the UI does not work, console is printing that index.html is not found (404). Is there a way to make this feature work? Is there anyone facing similar problem with the newest version of the Springboot?
[image: UI]

Here is my security configuration:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {
    private final JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthFilter;
    private final AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

    private static final String[] URL_WHITELIST = {
            ApplicationConstants.AUTH + "/**",
            ApplicationConstants.PARKING_SPOT + ID,
            "/error",
            "/favicon.ico",
            "/swagger-resources",
            "/swagger-resources/**",
            "/configuration/ui",
            "/configuration/security",
            "/swagger-ui.html",
            "/webjars/**",
            "/v3/api-docs/**",
            "/api/public/**",
            "/api/public/authenticate",
            "/actuator/*",
            "/swagger-ui/**"
    };

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                        .requestMatchers(URL_WHITELIST)
                        .permitAll()
                        .anyRequest()
                        .authenticated())
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

And OpenAPI initialization:

```java
@Configuration
public class OpenApiConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public OpenAPI openAPI() {
        Info info = new Info()
                .title("ParkingTime API")
                .version("1.0");
        return new OpenAPI().info(info);
    }
}
```

Pom:

```xml
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.18</version>
        </dependency>
```

console:

```
2023-11-17T10:56:36.805+01:00  WARN 8272 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : No mapping for GET /swagger-ui/index.html
2023-11-17T10:56:37.440+01:00  WARN 8272 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : No mapping for GET /swagger-ui/index.html
```

Comment: please be sure that you have imported `org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui` also as dependency

Comment: Same thing when I add webmvc-ui

Comment: remove `io.swagger.core.v3` from dependency

Comment: Removed, but same result.

Comment: could you access path `/swagger-ui/index.html` ?

Comment: Also are see this kind of  message in logs when you start the application`This generated password is for development use only. Your security configuration must be updated before running your application in production.` ?

Comment: There is no such message in the console.

Comment: Any reason why you're extending from `WebMvcConfigurationSupport`? If I remove that, the Swagger UI works perfectly fine for me.

Comment: Okay, you are the best. I thought that Spring security was blocking URL paths that were UI-based. With this extension I enable UI in the spring, in other words, SwaggerUI will be allowed on the spring security configuration. It is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, due to you extending from `WebMvcConfigurationSupport`, Spring Boot will skip the `WebMvcAutoConfiguration`, which in turn causes the Swagger UI autoconfiguration to be skipped as well.

The easiest way to solve this is to not extend from `WebmvcConfigurationSupport`. If you really need to provide additional configuraton, you could extend from `DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration`, but in most cases, you don't need to extend it at all.

Answer (score 0):

I am using spring boot 3 and latest `swagger-webmvc-api`,so as suggested by [@andrei-lisa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18364656/andrei-lisa) in comments I added `swagger-webmvc-ui` and got swagger-ui.html displayed